# When assigning pointer to pointer I get warning: assignment makes integer from pointer

Tags: c, pointers, gcc-warning

I hate posting this because there are so many of these, but none of them seem to address what I am seeing. The normal issues (undeclared functions, unintentional casts, misunderstanding of basic pointers) don't seem apply here. This is the stripped down version of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

extern void* malloc ( size_t size );

typedef struct {
    size_t      size;
    uint8_t*    buffer, curr, next;
} buffer_t;

void init( buffer_t* b, int size ) {
    b->size   = (size_t) size;
    b->buffer = (uint8_t*) malloc( sizeof(uint8_t) * b->size + 1 );
    b->curr   = (uint8_t*) b->buffer; // warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
    b->next   = (uint8_t*) b->buffer; // warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
}

int main ( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    buffer_t buf;

    init( &buf, 16 );

    return 0;
}
```

This fails without the casts, but putting them in makes it even more obvious.

I'm compiling on WinXP (yeah, yeah, yeah) under MinGW/MSYS with gcc 4.7.2. using the following command:

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -o testing test.c
```

Any help?

Comment: `malloc` is declared in `<stdlib.h>`. Why are you also declaring it yourself? (That's not related to your problem.)

Comment: Also, [you shouldn't cast the return value from `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), and you definitely don't need to cast `b->buffer` to `uint8_t*`, since it's already that type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ```
> uint8_t*    buffer, curr, next;
> ```

The way you wrote it, `buffer` is a pointer and `curr` and `next` are mere `uint8_t`s. You probably meant:

```
uint8_t    *buffer, *curr, *next;
```

Even better (less prone to errors) would be to have each field on its own line.

Comment: Thank you. That mental anguish I feel is stupidity leaving the brain.

Comment: @user2734029 No worries. Everyone makes this mistake from time to time: props for enabling warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared curr and next as uint8_t (and not a pointer to uint8_t) inside the structure declaration.
Try this instead.
**uint8_t *buffer,*curr,*next;**

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question.  Accepting your structure at face value and assuming curr and next should be pointers to other occurrences of the same structure (will also require code modification per other answers), then `init` should be coded as:

```
void init( buffer_t* b, int size ) {
    b->size   = (size_t) size;
    b->buffer = (uint8_t*) malloc( sizeof(uint8_t) * b->size + 1 );
    b->curr   = b;     // a self-pointer to this buffer_t
    b->next   = NULL;  // pointer to next buffer_t structure
}
```

`b->buffer` points to storage allocated on the heap, while the `buffer_t` structure is part of a linked list used to manage many different buffers.